# Checking an Array for number of occurences and outputting to new array. C

Tags: c, arrays

I need to loop through an array and find the occurrence of numbers in the array and then output the number of occurrences into a new array.

```
void create_hist(double input[], int num_of_inputs, int output[])
{
int num_to_check = input[0];
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < num_of_inputs; i++)
{
        if (input[i] == num_to_check)
        {
            counter++;  /* it was found */
        }
        output[i] = counter;    
}

return;
}
```

consider the input to consist of `input[3] ={0, 0 ,0}`. output should be `output[3] = {3, 0, 0}`.

the current output is `output[3] = {1, 2, 3}` -- do i need to create another array to hold the value of each loop and then make it output. I'm just lost on this one.

Comment: you need to get the current hit count out of output[i], add 1 to it and put it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here the problem is that your input array is `{0,0,0}` , so in starting you already initialized `num_to_check` to 0 ,so when you iterate through the for loop for first time the if condition is held true ,which increases counter by 1 ,in the next iteration the if statement is again true as both `input[1]` and `num_to_check` are 0 , so now counter increments again by 1 , and the same happens in the last iteration , that is the reason you are getting output as `{1,2,3}`.You do not need to create another array, just in place of `i` in the subscript of `output[i]` ,use some other variable `j` and increment it suitably.

Comment: mmm something i also need to do it count over another array that is

Comment: I also need to truncate an array of floating point numbers `input[5] = {0.0000, 1.000, 2.000, 3.0000, 4.00000} and obtain an int, then count how many times each integer in the range of 0-10 shows up. leaving an `output[5] = {1, 1, 1,1,1}`

Comment: First of all then make an array of type double instead of float otherwise you will face consequences and also the number you are going to input to check should also be double type ,after that as i already told you ,you can use a different variable j in the subscript of output and then increment j as required ,if you still have doubt i can make a code and show you

Answer (score 0):

Fist issue:
num_to _check should be double or you need to cast (if you want to check the integers) the array element.

I afraid the `==` is not the same as when comparing the integers, as the float number are not precise

```
#define delta  xxxx /*some double value*/ 

void create_hist(double input[], int num_of_inputs, int output[])
{
double num_to_check = input[0];
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < num_of_inputs; i++)
{
        if (input[i] > num_to_check - delta && input[i] < num_to_check + delta)
```

or

```
void create_hist(double input[], int num_of_inputs, int output[])
{
int num_to_check = input[0];
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < num_of_inputs; i++)
{
        if ((int)input[i] == num_to_check)
```

or

```
void create_hist(double input[], int num_of_inputs, int output[])
{
int num_to_check = input[0];
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < num_of_inputs; i++)
{
        if ((int)round(input[i]) == num_to_check)
```

depending of your program logic.

Answer (score 0):

So this works for the above.

```
void create_hist(double input[], int num_of_inputs, int output[])
{

int num_to_check = input[0];
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < num_of_inputs; i++)
{
    int j = output[i];
    if ((int)input[i] == num_to_check)
        {
            counter++;  /* it was found */
        }
        output[j] = counter;    
}

return;
```

another issue: if i have a floating point array

```
input[5] = {0.0000, 1.0000, 2.0000, 3.0000, 4.000}
```

and i want the then truncate the values to int, and count how many times each integer in the range 0 - 10 appears in the input array then output it to:

```
output[5] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

how do i do this.